# Dual ttys on Ubuntu 20.10 console

Tags: apt, updates, 20.10

I have a custom server build AMD that has been misbehaving for a while.  I lost a RAID-5 array (storage not OS) and had to do quite a bit of work to rebuild it and decided to attempt to fix my problems.

Hardware:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
RAM: G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin PC RAM DDR4 4000
SAS/SATA controller: Adaptec 3154-16i
Boot drive: NVMe - SAMSUNG 980 PRO M.2 2280 1TB PCI-Express Gen 4.0 x4
Video: ASUS GeForce GT 1030 2GB Phoenix Fan OC Edition HDMI DVI Graphics Card
Mobo: ASRock X570 TAICHI RAZER Edition AM4 AMD X570 SATA 6Gb/s

My history:

Long-term Unix experience (> 30 years), systems-level mainframe, storage expert, Windows, database, etc.

My original install worked pretty well - but I had Gnome desktop issues.  Eventually, Gnome quit working and my console login was all I could do.

Attempting login would show characters of my typing that should not be echoed. (password characters)
When I was able to get logged in, I would see another tty prompt.  Doing anything on the console was hit or miss.  Some of the characters would be accepted by the login others would go to the tty login prompt.

I can remotely do a startx command and get windowing to work, but I would rather have the console fire up Gnome desktop like it originally did.

Other issues:
apt and apt-get update is broken - getting errors attempting to contact the archive.ubuntu.com and ppa.launchpad.net sites.

Actual errors:

Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease Err:10
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/iconnor/zoneminder-1.36/ubuntu groovy InRelease Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' no longer has a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I am happy to provide GRUB file contents or any other things - just need a bit of help to get started.  When I get back on the path - I should be good.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Don't forget **after** a releases reaches its EOL, some archives get moved & others (esp. if mirrors) are *dropped*. Your issue is the EOL release; and you've left it too late to *release-upgrade* and the upgrade path for 20.10 is now gone with 21.04 EOL too.  20.10 tells you it's the 2020-October release; so calculating the EOL is just adding 9 months to 20.10; or you can just add 3 months after replacement was released being 21.04 or 2021-April.

Comment: I am fully willing to upgrade - I need a path to get there.  If I knew where the archive references were, I could comment out the non-working paths.  I just do not know Ubuntu that well yet.  One simple suggestion was all I needed.  I fell into this hole primarily because my server console was problematic and Gnome was not working.  Upgrades are really hard when you have a headless server and only rsh/telnet access from remote systems. (hoping to address that)

Comment: The automatic upgrade tools will only upgrade you to a *supported* release; which is a problem given Ubuntu 20.10 had one upgrade path (it wasn't a LTS release that had two options); it upgraded to 21.04 which is now EOL - thus your intended & QA-tested upgrade path is gone. The fully-supported upgrade path now is re-install as you missed your 9 month window for *supported* upgrade. Desktop installs allow a *upgrade via re-install* option but it's not intended for servers (which are intended to be maintained/managed; usually using LTS releases). I'd suggest a LTS install next time.

Comment: FYI:  Read my first comment which provided the link for EOLUpgrades.  It's for sure what I'd try, but I believe you'll end up with a *unsupported upgrade path* error message as you've missed the upgrade window.

Comment: Thanks - I can do a clean install and restore all my files.  Just was having issues - and still am which I am hoping a clean install of an LTS release will cure.  The tty0 and tty1 at login after boot still freaks me out a bit. :-)  When you have the situation I found myself in - where I only did rsh/telnet, the unsupported version information was easy to miss.  I would have chosen more wisely (just got latest version) if I knew about it at the time.